# Pass value of selected row of datagrid to popup box

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a popupbox which is shown on every row and when I click on that popup it should show the more details of the selected row. I was able to get values of selected row but I am unable to bind them to popupbox controls.

```xaml
<DataGrid x:Name="CRDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCR}" FontSize="14" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding crentities}"
CanUserDeleteRows="False" md:DataGridAssist.ColumnHeaderPadding="4" md:DataGridAssist.CellPadding="4" SelectionUnit="FullRow" MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected" HeadersVisibility="All" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="20" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding LogName}" Width="80"   />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="MUIdentifier" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding MU_Identifier}" Width="100"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Status}" Width="80" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="RequestType" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding RequestType}" Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="DateTime" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Create_Date,TargetNullValue='-'}"  Width="100" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="SoftwareVersion" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding SW_Version}" Width="200"  />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <md:PopupBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" PlacementMode="BottomAndAlignRightEdges" StaysOpen="True">
                        <md:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
                            <md:PackIcon Kind="DotsHorizontal" Margin="4 0 4 0" Width="24" Height="24"
                                Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=md:PopupBox}, Path=Foreground}" />
                        </md:PopupBox.ToggleContent>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=CRDataGrid, Path= SelectedCR.MU_Identifier}" />
                    </md:PopupBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Popups are usually not in the same VisualTree as the elements are are placed on, so the RelativeSource will not find anything. If you want to use their (apparent) parent's data you need to navigate your binding via `PlacementTarget` (or whatever it is called in your specific implementation - btw, doesn't seem stock, which one are you using?).

Comment: I am using materialdesign popupbox and this is the namespace xmlns:md="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes" , I will check placement target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=CRDataGrid, Path= SelectedCR.MU_Identifier}" />
```

instead be

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=CRDataGrid, Path= SelectedItem.MU_Identifier}" />
```

?

Comment: It worked awesome, this also reflects in my viewmodel. so i learnt if we are binding by elements name we should use that element tags to bind.